# CefSharp 117.2.40.0 when used in VB6 MDI child, renders locked grey screen when restoring minimized window

Tags: .net, vb6, controls, cefsharp

I'm using the WinForms package v117.2.40 in a .Net WinForms user control.  I've got the control working in an existing VB6 app with late binding, I can redirect to new URLs no issue.  I can use the VB6 app's Window menu to switch between the Cef browser MDI child and other MDI child windows without issue.

The issue I do have is, in the VB6 app (which uses MDI windows), if I CTRL-TAB between MDI windows, the Cef Browser goes grey and the container control (with the File menu / address bar) is disabled.  However if I double click the area to the right of the File menu, this seems to re-enable the Cef Browser control, the File menu becomes responsive again and instead of a grey area, the browser contents are displayed.

My question after a lot of headbashing and research is: does the WinForms version of the Cef browser disable itself when the parent window is minimized?  I couldn't find anything in WinForms for the most similar issue I Googled, which the solution was to override the OnBrowserWasHidden method with no code.  Any pointers would be really appreciated

When I switch from one MDI child window to another using CTRL-TAB, I expect the Cef browser control to not be in some "locked" state

Comment: You can debug the source to get a better understanding of what's going on https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/117/CefSharp.WinForms/Internals/ParentFormMessageInterceptor.cs#L129

Comment: Thanks for the hint, much appreciated

Comment: The thing is, even manually restoring and maximizing the window that contains the CefSharp control doesn't make it redisplay.  The only thing that reactivates the control is a double click to the area to the right of the control's File menu.  I don't think this is a CefSharp specific thing, it seems more like a VB6 and .Net control issue

Comment: As a test you can try disabling the ParentFormMessageInterceptor. Set the following property to false. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/117/CefSharp.WinForms/ChromiumWebBrowser.cs#L237

Comment: Looking through the .Net code (I was using the Cef DLLs previously) I found that the control Visible was false when using CTRL-TAB instead of the WIndow menu.  Once I found that, in the .Net control code I just had to set the control.Visible to true (I was trying the browser control visible previously, rather than the .Net control itself)